# Using Google Place API to get events

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm trying to get current nearby events using the Place API. I'm currently following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search), but I can't get the event array in the return JSON object. Can someone please let me know what I'm going wrong.

This is my search url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&location=38.9283,77.1753&radius=10000&sensor=false&key=

Thanks.

Comment: yes: AIzaSyB9I2pc5KFJ9g8JkzohA4sZD02HSOuQSZw

Comment: wht do you mean by  I can't get the event array in the return JSON object

Comment: this is what i need from the search result:                        An events[]: array or one or more <event> elements provide information about current events happening at this Place. Up to three events are returned for each place, ordered by start time. For information about events, please read Events in the Places API. https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchResults. But it is not returned when I search.

Comment: Dear there is an problen in your api key that's why you are not getting the json result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Developer Console -> APIs & Services then Click near button +Enable APIs And Services -> Click Places API Tile Then Find the  Button Enable

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                                    sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + ","
                                            + mLongitude);
                                    sb.append("&radius=5000");

                                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                                    sb.append("&key=YOUR KEY");
```